# Issues Reloading JS Datatables with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, meteor, datatables

I’m running into an issue with Javascript Datatables. I’m a newbie when it comes to Javascript, so apologies in advance if I get terminology or concepts incorrect. My application I’m building is going to be able to list items in an AWS bucket and have the ability to download/delete them. I’m working on the delete part right now and I have the AWS deletion on the server side working with user validation. However, when I go to update the table, I’m met with an error.

I have an ajax function defined in my datatable that calls my “refreshList” method on the server side that returns the updated list contents. This is used to populate the table. I want to run the ajax function again to refresh my table data, but when I call `template.table.ajax.reload()`, I get the following error: `TypeError: xhr.abort is not a function.` I’ve tried to Google for this to no avail, so I’ve been digging around the client code for the last little bit and found that this “xhr” object that should apparently have an abort function is instead a Promise that’s fulfilled with undefined in the result.

After Google was no help, I tried deleting and completely reloading the table, but that just essentially refreshes the page, bringing you right back to the start of your list if you're multiple pages in. Also tried table.ajax.url().load() but that didn't work either.

I'm expecting the table to reload like [this](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) says it should, but am only getting the error.

Has anyone had any experience with this error in the past and were you able to solve it?

Edit: Here's some more info on how I'm filling my datatable. I'm using Meteor, here’s my table initialization and what my delete button does:

```
Template.Home.onRendered(async function () {
    this.table = $('#bucketItemTable').DataTable({
        "ajax": async function(data, callback, settings) {
            const tableData = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                // This call returns a list of items to display in the table
                Meteor.call("refreshList", (error, result) => {
                    if (error) return reject(error);
                    resolve(result);
                });
            });

            callback( { data: tableData } );
        }
    });
});

Template.Home.events({
    // Delete button first deletes item from bucket, then reloads table
    'click .btn-delete': async function(e, template) {
        ... // Meteor call to delete item from bucket, not relevant

        template.table.ajax.reload();
    }
});
```

Not exactly sure what else to add that would make it reproducible, because it doesn't sound like it happens very often based on the lack of Google results. I'll try starting from scratch, but that'll take a while.

An Update:
I tried making a new project with a basic datatable and it still refused to reload because of the same issue. Will continue to diagnose.

Final Update:
I was able to get it to work by wrapping my promise in a function. Apparently ajax doesn't like running promises directly, so you have to wrap it in a function? Idk, it's all black magic to me.

```
"ajax": async function(data, callback, settings) {
    let ajaxFunc = async function () {
        const tableData = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // This call returns a list of items to display in the table
            Meteor.call("refreshList", (error, result) => {
                if (error) return reject(error);
                resolve(result);
            });
        });

        callback( { data: tableData } );
    }
    ajaxFunc();
}
```

Comment: You can [edit] your question to provide a [mre]: the smallest amount of code and data needed for us to reliably recreate the issue.

Comment: Just made an edit. As I say in it, I'm not sure exactly how to make it repeatable since it doesn't seem to be happening to anyone else. I'll try starting from scratch but that'll take a while

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work by wrapping my promise in a function. Apparently ajax doesn't like running promises directly, so you have to wrap it in a function? Idk, it's all black magic to me.

```
"ajax": async function(data, callback, settings) {
    let ajaxFunc = async function () {
        const tableData = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // This call returns a list of items to display in the table
            Meteor.call("refreshList", (error, result) => {
                if (error) return reject(error);
                resolve(result);
            });
        });

        callback( { data: tableData } );
    }
    ajaxFunc();
}
```